# PHP preg_replace title(non-english characters) to clean slug not working

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm attempting to turn Titles to slugs

```
$string = "آزمون پادشاهی متحده";
$pattern = '/[`~!@#$%^&*()_|+\=?;:..’“\'"<>,€£¥•،٫؟»«\{\}\[\]\\\/]+/gi';
            $replacement = '';

            $slug = trim(preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string));
            $slug = str_replace(" ","-",$slug);
```

The end result should be `آزمون-پادشاهی-متحده` spaces replaced by hyphen.

Another example
title: `Great Britain` 
slug: `great-britain`

How do i solve?

Comment: PHP regex does not support `g`. Besides, you need `u` modifier. Try `$pattern = '/[`~!@#$%^&*()_|+\=?;:..’“\'"<>,€£¥•،٫؟»«\{\}\[\]\\\\\/]+/ui';`

Comment: You need use regex twice. First remove additional character and then replace space with `-`

Comment: Try `$pattern = '/[\`~!@#$%^&*()_|+\=?;:..’“\'"<>,€£¥•،٫؟»«\{\}\[\]\\\\\/]+/ui';`. There seems to be a problem with an unescaped ``\`` in the pattern beside the `u` modifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply the following fixes here:

- Escape the backslash matching pattern, that is, `'\\\\'`
- Remove the `g` modifier as it is not supported by PHP `preg_replace` (it replaces all occurrence in the input by default)
- Add a `u` modifier to enable PCRE engine to parse both the pattern and input as Unicode strings.

Use

```
$string = "آزمون پادشاهی متحده";
$pattern = '/[`~!@#$%^&*()_|+=?;:..’“\'"<>,€£¥•،٫؟»«{}[\]\\\\\/]+/ui';
$replacement = '';

 $slug = trim(preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string));
 $slug = str_replace(" ","-",$slug);
 echo $slug;
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/YUsQs).

Note that `[`, `=`, `{` and `}` are not special inside a character class and need no escaping.